# make pin draggable and long click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I've been trying for hours to make the pin draggable in MapKit, but it seems that the pin is so stubborn it didn't want to move.

this is my code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

protocol AddCoffeeDelegate {
    func viewController(vc: AddCoffeeViewController, didAddCoffee coffee : Coffee! )
}

class AddCoffeeViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

    @IBOutlet weak var coffeeName: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var coffeeRating: UITextField!

    var coffee: Coffee?
    var delegate: AddCoffeeDelegate?



    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var coreLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var locationManager : LocationManager!
    var savedLocation : CLLocation?


    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKPointAnnotation {
            let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myPin")

            pinAnnotationView.pinTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
            pinAnnotationView.draggable = true
            pinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = false
            pinAnnotationView.animatesDrop = true

            return pinAnnotationView
        }

        return nil
    }



    func getLocation(){
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocationWithCompletionHandler { (latitude, longitude, status, verboseMessage, error) -> () in
            self.displayLocation(CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude))
        }
    }

    func displayLocation(location: CLLocation){
        mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)), animated: true)


        let locationPinCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        annotation.title = "My Title"
        annotation.subtitle = "My Subtitle"
        annotation.coordinate = locationPinCoord
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

        savedLocation = location
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status != CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined || status !=  CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied || status != CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted {
            getLocation()
        }
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        coreLocationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager = LocationManager.sharedInstance

        let authorizationCode = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

        if authorizationCode == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined && coreLocationManager.respondsToSelector("requestAlwaysAuthorization") || coreLocationManager.respondsToSelector("requestWhenInUseAuthorization"){
            if NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription") != nil {
                coreLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            }else{
                print("no desscription provided ")
            }
        }else{
            getLocation()
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func cancel(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {

        var createdCoffee = Coffee()
        createdCoffee.name = self.coffeeName.text!
        createdCoffee.rating = Double(self.coffeeRating.text!)!
        createdCoffee.place = savedLocation
        self.coffee = createdCoffee
        self.delegate?.viewController(self, didAddCoffee: self.coffee)
    }




}
```

I have tried every related issue with mapkit in swift, but it seems that the pin won't drag itself.Where could the problem be? I have already set the title and  implement the MKMapViewDelegate protocol, but still it wont drag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the delegate of the mapview to the view controller either in code, or via the Storyboard?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.delegate = self
    ...
}
```